# Is it possible to check in at the gate or the transit hall at Cochin?

Tags: visas, transit, india, check-in

In 4 days, I am flying from Kuala Lumpur to Cochin, India and 3 hours later, I have a connecting flight with IndiGo to Dubai.

IndiGo only checks in international flight passengers at the airport. Does this mean I have to go through Immigration, just to check in (I know I would need visa)? I have only carry on luggage. Is it possible to check in at the gate or in the airside transit hall?

Comment: Are you flying on the same ticket or using two separate tickets? If latter, you would need visa anyway as otherwise you won't be allowed to board in KUL.

Comment: As far as I can find, right now, there doesn't appear to be an airside/sterile transit area in Cochin, meaning you would go through Immigration, and need a visa.

Comment: Yeah, i messaged the airlines but they take forever to reply so i applied for the visa. Thanks everyone :)r

Comment: After your experience, why don't you answer your own question, with the details? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=IN&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by check-in staff:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours

In practice, for TWOV, check-in staff at most airports require the trip to be in a single booking. With separate tickets, Conchin would count as the final destination to them, whereby you will need at least a transit visa.